# Can't get mouseleave() or mouseout() to work in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on this page: http://www.problemio.com/index_new.php

When you mouse over the "health" link, I got the popup to pop-up, but have a hard time getting it to close.

Here is what I did to make the popup show up:

```
$("<div id='pop'>" + div_contents + "</div>").dialog( { title: 'Secondary Categories'} );
```

and here is how I am trying to make it close:

```
$('#hea_link').mouseout(function() 
{       
    $("#pop").dialog( 'close' );                
});

$('#hea_link').mouseleave(function() 
{       
    $("#pop").dialog( 'close' );                
});
```

Neither of the ways I am trying to get the popup to close works. Also, I have no idea why clicking the x on top-right of the popup doesn't close it.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You're making like 1000 of those dialogs when you mouse over. Try making only *one* and your code should work.

Comment: FYI: You also open more than one dialog. You should create new dialog, but toggle it's visibility. Probably there are also issues with the ID beind used multiple times.

Comment: your close x works in the example however you seem to be opening two dialogs when you hover over. So you have to click close twice >?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems:

Every time you hover over that link another `<div id='pop'></div>` is created. I would recommend creating the dialog up-front and showing/hiding/populating it as necessary:

Add the following HTML to your page:

```
<div id='pop' style='display:none'></div>
```

Then when the page loads (in `document.ready` or similar):

```
$("#pop").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
```

The other issue you have is that looking at your code, it looks like you're only passing `hover` one function. That means that function will be executed on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Pass two functions to `hover`:

```
$('#hea_link').hover(function() 
{       
    $("#pop").dialog( 'open' );                
},
function () 
{
    $("#pop").dialog("close");
});
```

Using hover  this way means you don't need a `mouseout` / `mouseleave` event listener either.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jNq9X/